# how to change data already data in spinner

Tags: android

I have four Spinner ,First spinner display data when user select on spinner item data then other spinner data is displayed .First time,i have loaded all data in spinner when user select first spinner then data should be changed to refresh to second Spinner

How data is changed in second spinner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you would need to get a reference of your spinner like -

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, R.array.myArray, android.R.layout.mySpinnerItem);
 adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.myDropdownItem);
 spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

To change the values you would do -

```
public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
  View view, int pos, long id) {
     //change content 
  }
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
      //do nothing
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a listener on the `setOnItemSelectedListener` of your first `Spinner`, with the appropriate code to populate your second `Spinner`. This way when you change the value of the first `Spinner`, the second `Spinner` will be updated.

Comment: i have told,data is loaded in all spinner.when first spinner is clicked then second spinner data is refreshed ...